# List all files and regkeys opened by a program?

Tags: windows, debug

On Windows, I have a currently installed application. The setup utility has since disappeared but we'd like to 'install' the program on another machine. It is quite a well-contained piece of software so we're not anticipating a huge number of dependant files or registry keys.

The likes of `lsof` and `strace` would be great but these utilities (AFAIK) aren't available on Windows.

Is there a utility for Windows that will enable us to see all the files and registry keys that a process read/writes to through execution?

Answer (score 1):

SysInternals ProcessExplorer gives you an overview of all running processes and the handles they have open (including file and registry).

SysInternals ProcessMonitor let's you monitor file and registry accesses of all running processes.

Both can be downloaded from [Sysinternals Process Utilities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx) webpage.